# Can Putty establish a gateway to the SSH remote server?

Tags: networking, command-line, putty, ssh-tunnel

My desktop home computer (see the image below) connects via **SSH to the Office Server** (via internet, of course).

I connect to that server **from my home desktop** (running Linux) by using the **OpenSSH client** from Linux (note the `-g` for "gateway" switch):

```
ssh MyUser@OfficePublicIP -L 22222:172.26.0.10:22 -g
```

So, when the connection is made, I have a running SSH **tunnel to the server** for my LAN:

```
luis@HomeDesktop:~$ netstat -ano | grep "22222" -i
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22222           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
```

And now I can go to my **home laptop** and open an SSH session to the office server via my Home Desktop (running Windows) using PuTTY by doing:

```
PuTTY 192.168.0.101 -P 22222
```

The process is shown in this **scheme** (follow the black line **arrows**):

[image: Home Desktop acting as gateway to Office Server for my Home Laptop]

The **problem** is: I **need to run Windows** on my home desktop, instead of Linux. And I certainly **prefer to use** the [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) SSH client (I like its terminal configurability).

But Putty v0.63 seems **not to have this -g (gateway)** option that allows external connections to forwarded (tunnelized) ports.

I have done a research through the putty help .chm file, but nor Putty neither its associated tool PLink seem to have this option.

Does anyone know **how to tunnelize** connections to the office server from my home desktop, but **keep using PuTTY**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... in fact, if what you want is **only the neat PuTTY window** for writing in the remote SSH session, you can use it only for that, and establish the tunnel by using (simultaneously in another console) any other **SSH client** port from Linux to Windows.

For example, the **OpenSSH client** from [CygWin](http://cygwin.com/) should work OK:

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.6p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014

$ ssh
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
           [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec]
           [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-Q cipher | cipher-auth | mac | kex | key]
           [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port]
           [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] [user@]hostname [command]
```

Syntax is, by the way, the same you are using when you run Linux on your home desktop.

```
ssh MyUser@OfficePublicIP -L 22222:172.26.0.10:22 -g
```

Answer (score 0):

You can patch/simulate the **gateway** option by simultaneously running in your home desktop a **simple port forwarder** in another port.

For example, I often use [Port Forwarding for Windows](http://www.quantumg.net/portforward.php) (I do prefer the "old command line utility", so I can automate it via scripting). In your case, say 11111TCP will be the "transitional" port:

```
c:\>trivial_portforward.exe 11111 127.0.0.1 22222
```

**Check** that both port are listening by doing (on your home desktop):

```
c:\>netstat -ano | grep "11111" -i
TCP    0.0.0.0:11111          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       6724

netstat -ano | grep "22222" -i
TCP    127.0.0.1:22222        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       6028
```

And now, you can do **from your laptop**:

```
c:\>PuTTY 192.168.0.101 -P 11111
```

The SSH connection must succees. At the same time you should see on the `trivial_portforward` console the confirmation:

```
received connection from 192.168.0.102
connection to 127.0.0.1:22222 established
```

NOTE: You must use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` (remember that your problem is that there is no redirection with PuTTY but for `127.0.0.1`).

Answer (score 0):

Using Putty/Kitty :

```
putty.exe MyUser@OfficePublicIP -L 0.0.0.0:22222:172.26.0.10:22
```

Note the `0.0.0.0:` part, that specifies `any host` for **incoming connections** to the SSH tunnel on the server. This is the equivalent to `-g` on **OpenSSH** .

Note the (this time proper) results of `netstat` command on the Windows machine:

```
C:\>netstat -ano | grep "22222" -i
TCP    0.0.0.0:22222        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       6028
```